# Extending variable scope from one frame to another frame

Tags: java, swing, scope, jframe

I have two `JFrame` based windows: `SeatLayout` and `BillSummary`. I need to get the `seatnumber`  from the `SeatLayout` frame and display it in `BillSummary` but the variable scope is limited to the first frame.

How can I do this?

Comment: Give `SeatLayout` a `public int getSeatNumber()` method that returns the seat number; then give `BillSummary` a reference to the `SeatLayout`, which it can then use to call the `getSeatNumber()` method on that `SeatLayout`.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple JFrame is a bad practice and it should be avoided. 
Reason being, it will add more problems in the future and it will be nightmare to maintain.

To answer your question , how to pass variable from your parent(JFrame) to a child(JDialog) .This can achive by using JDialog.

I am going to run through an example. 
lets say, your BillSummary.java is ....

```
//BillSummary Class
public class billSummary {
   JFrame frame;
   billSummary(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

  public void launchbillSummary(int seatNumber) {
    // Create a dialog that suits your ui , you can use JPanel as your layout container
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Bill Summary", true);
    dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    dialog.setSize(100, 100);
    dialog.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(seatNumber)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

Your seatLayout.java

```
public class seatLayout {

 seatLayout(){  
    //Lets say you have seleted seat number 10
    int defaultSeatNumber = 10;

    //Lets say you have a button and when it is clicked , you pass the data to billsummary page
    JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");

    //Your seatLayout GUI
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("seat layout");
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.add(enter);

    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //Do your passing of data/ price of calculation here
            //You pass the data that to your custom dialog -> Bill summary 
            new billSummary(frame).launchbillSummary(defaultSeatNumber);
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new seatLayout();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I hope this help and answers your question. Good luck :)